# How to get each flexbox to fill up one line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is what I'm trying to achieve: [image]

I want each child to fill up one line by it self. Here is my code:

```
main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}



.first {
    background: #999999;
    flex-grow: 1;
    order: 1;
    margin: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 

}


.second {
    background: #999999;
    flex-grow: 1;
    order: 3;
    margin: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 

}





.third {
    background: #999999;
    flex-grow: 1;
    order: 3;
    margin: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 

}



.fourth {
    background: #999999;
    flex-grow: 1;
    order: 3;
    margin: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 

}



.first,.second,.third,.fourth{
    margin: 20px 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width:  5px 5px 5px 5px;
```

One thing that did actually work was to remove the whole main, so thats an option. Just curious to see if there are better solutions, as I feel like remvoing the main is a bit weird. Appreciate any help!

Comment: All you need is `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` on the parent. You don't even need to use flexbox for a layout like this, btw. This is the default behavior of block level elements. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgQaZM If you're having problems, post ALL of your code (HTML, too) and put it in the code editor in your post (looks like a `<>`) with a [mcve]

Comment: I see! thank you so much<3

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Coker said in the comments: You don't necessarily need flexbox for this, as block level elements will be displayed beneath each other per default:

```css
.container > div {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
  color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div>1</div>
 <div>2</div>
 <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Anyway if you need to use flexbox for some reason, you can use [`flex-direction: column;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) on the container element:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container > div {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
  color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div>1</div>
 <div>2</div>
 <div>3</div>
</div>
```